# How to change Application in app.xml (XSSF) with NPOI?

Tags: c#, openxml, npoi

Unzipping an .xlsx generated with NPOI I noticed that NPOI set itself as "Application" in docProps/app.xml and also added "Generator" to docProps/custom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
    <Application>NPOI</Application>
    <AppVersion>123.456</AppVersion>
</Properties>
```

How do I edit the Application information in app.xml?

I only found `CoreProperties`, `CustomProperties` and `ExtendedProperties`, but nothing called "AppProperties".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the underlying properties from the `ExtendedProperties` and then set the `Application` property of that. The following example sets the Application and AppVersion:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

    POIXMLProperties props = workbook.GetProperties();

    //get the underlying properties (of type NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_ExtendedProperties)
    var underlyingProps = props.ExtendedProperties.GetUnderlyingProperties();
    //now set the properties (excuse the vanity!)
    underlyingProps.Application = "petelids";
    underlyingProps.AppVersion = "1.0";

    FileStream sw = File.Create("test.xlsx");
    workbook.Write(sw);
    sw.Close();
}
```

### Generator properties

Example of changing the `Generator` in `CustomProperties` (custom.xml).

```
CustomProperties customProperties = properies.CustomProperties;
customProperties.AddProperty("Generator", "petelids");
customProperties.AddProperty("Generator Version", "1.0");
```

Comment: Looking a bit closer at app.xml I can see that it's schema is indeed [`ExtendedProperties`](http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MikaelDúiBolinder. Apologies as I'd missed that part of your question.